# WCF Rest WebService working good locally but return HTTP 400 externaly

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I am building a WFC Rest web service. 
This service containe POST operation who work correctly when I consume it locally. but when I tried to consume it from external IP but it return a HTTP 400.

This is the web service Interface :

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "Login")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               UriTemplate = "Login")]
    string Login(Stream data);
```

Do you have any idea about this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try enabling tracing for the server, the traces should contain some exception which explains why it's returning a 400 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling Tracing on your service and inspect the trace logs to see where your request is failing. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: Thank you guys. I found the damned exception.
But why this exception is not thrown when I call the service from the host it self ?